How to programmatically embed a Webview in the Secondary Sidebar in a VSCode extension?
I'm developing a VSCode extension and I want to open a Webview in the Secondary Sidebar without requiring the user to drag it manually. I would like to know if it's possible to directly create and embed a Webview in the Secondary Sidebar through programming.

Is it possible to create a view directly in the secondary sidebar?
Is there any command that can replace the drag function?


Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

No, it isn't possible to create a view directly in the Auxiliary Sidebar as the Auxiliary/Secondary Side Bar is not currently a ViewContainer to contribute to.
There is an open issue on this, see Allow extensions to add views to the secondary side bar with a lot of votes and a commit but no action lately.

"Is there any command that can replace the drag function?"
There is a View: Move View command but I don't know if it is designed to take arguments like
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.moveView', { viewIds: ['workbench.view.debug'], destinationId: 'workbench.view.explorer'} );

which only opens the dialog box.
Perhaps Gama11 knows?

issues#151681 I subscribed to this thread.
Anyway, thank you.
